# Image as a variable then insert it using FPDF and PHP

Tags: php, image, fpdf

So, I am new to fpdf. Maybe someone knows how to get an image with a variable and then insert it in a cell. There is something wrong with my sintax.

```
$image1 = "../_resources/img/xstampa/stampa_18_grey.png";

$stampanumero = $letterposition[$position].$image1;
$p->Cell(7, 5, $stampanumero, 1,'L');
```

The problem is that $image1 is printed as text ../_resources/img/xstampa/stampa_18_grey.png. It does not grab the image.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inserting an image with PHP and FPDF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471441/inserting-an-image-with-php-and-fpdf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this way:
So create image with

```
$p->Cell(7, 5,$p->Image('../_resources/img/xstampa/stampa_18_grey.png',10,10,-300), 1,'L');
```

Comment: Would have been better as a comment

Comment: why ? keep it because it helps other