# FPDF produces a numeric value in cell when inserting image

Tags: php, image-processing, fpdf

Im using FPDF to render data in a table layout. All fine, until i want to insert a image into a Cell (or MultiCell. Both do the same). The image apears but it also produces a numeric value.

The number seems to be the number of times the image is used throughout the document...

```
    $interal_icon = 'resources/img/logo-icon.png';
    $im = $pdf->Image($interal_icon,$pdf->GetX(),$pdf->GetY(),0,0,'','','C',false,300,'',false,false,0,false,false,false,'');
    $pdf->Cell( 30, 8, $im, 0 , 0, '' , false,'',0,false,'','C' );
```

When i align the image different, the number will be aligned with it, so it has something to do with the image function i guess...

Anyone got an idea? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One 'solution' is **not** using cells. When i insert the image outside the cell functions it works fine...

Still bothers me :(

```
$pdf->Cell( 30, 8, '', 0 , 0, 'L' );
$pdf->Image($interal_icon,PDF_MARGIN_LEFT,$pdf->GetY(),10,10,'','','C',false,300,'',false,false,0,false,false,false,'');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should use the image function 'inline' instead of referring to a variable and using that one. That is at least what I read in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471441/inserting-an-image-with-php-and-fpdf).