# Load blob image in fpdf

Tags: oracle, blob, fpdf

I am trying to load an image from oracle database Blob file. To load image i am using the following code

```
$COM_CODE = 'O003';  
$sql = 'select DIGI_SIGN from LC_BLOCK_LIST_TECH_PERS where COM_CODE :COM_CODE';
$s = oci_parse ($c, $sql);
oci_bind_by_name($s, ':COM_CODE', $COM_CODE);
oci_execute($s, OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT);
$arr = oci_fetch_assoc($s);
$result = $arr['DIGI_SIGN']->load();
$pdf->Cell(40,5,$result,0,1,'L',0);
```

Nedd to show the image in a cell. In last cell i am not able to show the image instead binary value shows up.
what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471441/inserting-an-image-with-php-and-fpdf), it looks like you need to first create a file, then use standard procedure to write the image to the pdf:

```
$result = $arr['DIGI_SIGN']->load();
// Here: new question: [php] how to write  image file from Oracle BLOB?
// $result goes to a file on server:  "/var/appli/img/products/image1.jpg"

$image1 = "/var/appli/img/products/image1.jpg";
$pdf->Cell( 40, 5, $pdf->Image($image1, $pdf->GetX(), $pdf->GetY(), 30), 0, 1, 'L', 0);
```

Hope it helps.