# fpdf create a pdf with 3 images on the same line

Tags: php, fpdf

I try with fpdf to create a pdf with 3 images in the same line at the end of the texts. first image on the left, second in the center and third on the right. I do not get it.
Do you have any idea how it can be done?[image]

```
// Set font
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
// Move to 8 cm to the right
$pdf->Cell(80);
// Texto centrado en una celda con cuadro 20*10 mm y salto de línea
$pdf->Cell(80,10,"Parte trabajo Nr: $id",0,1,'C');
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',11);
//$pdf->Cell(20,10,"Documento $codigo_interno",0,1,'C');
//$pdf->Cell(20,10,"Documento $codigo_interno",0,1,'C');
//$pdf->Cell(20,10,"Documento $codigo_interno",0,1,'C');
//$pdf->Cell(20,10,"Documento $codigo_interno",0,1,'C');
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->Ln();
//\n pon esto para dar otralinia obligatoriamente
$pdf->Multicell(0,5," Fecha inicio: $fi , fecha final: $ff . Trabajo realizado por $nombre $apelido."); 
$pdf->Ln(); //es para dar una linia mas abajo
if($cliente==""){
    
}else{
$pdf->Multicell(0,5," En la instalacion del cliente : $cliente, con la dieccion: $direccion . \n Correo electronico: $correo, telefono: $telefono \n "); 
}
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->Multicell(0,5," $anotacion "); 
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->Multicell(0,5," $observacion ");
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->Multicell(0,5, $pdf->Multicell(0,0," Nombre Empresa:", $border=0, $align='L', $fill=false) . $pdf->Multicell(0,0,"Operario:", $border=0, $align='C', $fill=false) . $pdf->Multicell(0,0,"Cliente:", $border=0, $align='R', $fill=false), $border=0, $align='L', $fill=false); 

$pdf->Multicell(0,5, $pdf->Multicell(0,0," $empresa", $border=0, $align='L', $fill=false) . $pdf->Multicell(0,0,"$nombre $apelido", $border=0, $align='C', $fill=false) . $pdf->Multicell(0,0,"$cliente", $border=0, $align='R', $fill=false), $border=0, $align='L', $fill=false); 


$firma_empleado="ftp://$ftp_username:$ftp_userpass@$ftp_server/$firma";
$firma_cliente2="ftp://$ftp_username:$ftp_userpass@$ftp_server/$firma_cliente";

$pdf->Ln();




$pdf->Multicell(0,5, $pdf->Image($firma_empresa, $pdf->GetX(), $pdf->GetY(), 33.78) . $pdf->Image($firma_empleado, $pdf->GetX(), $pdf->GetY(), 33.78) . $pdf->Image($firma_cliente2, $pdf->GetX(), $pdf->GetY(), 33.78), $border=0, $align='L', $fill=false);
```

Comment: Please share your code and what you have tried

Comment: Hello, i think that u can find answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471441/inserting-an-image-with-php-and-fpdf

Comment: is not working this

Comment: Calling `MultiCell()` inside a `MultiCell()` makes no sense.